# How to handle parent/child relationship between markdown posts in GatsbyJS

Tags: graphql, markdown, gatsby

I was wondering if there an elegant solution to handle two-level parent/child relationship in Gatsby?

I’m building a website showcasing the products, where some of the products have several variants.

I have the following two levels folder structure for my project:

```
src/posts
│
└───Product_A
│   │   index.md
│   │   image.png
│   │ 
│   └───Variants
│       └───Variant_1
│       │   index.md
│       │
│       └───Variant_2
│       │   index.md
│   
└───Product_B
│   │   index.md
│   
└───Product_C
│   │   index.md
│   │
│   └───Variants
...
```

Each product folder contains an article in markdown, images and optionally *Variants* folder (for those products that have one or more variants).
I'm also using Markdown frontmatter to describe product properties both for parent and child products.

I have to display products and its variants on home page in a "collapsed" way (displaying product and its number of variants together) and an expanded way (displaying all products and its variants in a flat structure) like this:

[image: homepage]

On a product page I have to display products variants for those products that have them like this:

[image]

And I'll also have to determine if the product is parent or child and show slightly different design/content on a product page based on that.

I'm currently trying to use GraphQL filter in combination with `fileAbsolutePath` to fetch variations for a particular product:

```
  allMarkdownRemark( filter: {fileAbsolutePath: {glob: "**/Product_A/Variants/**"}}){
    edges {
      node {
        fileAbsolutePath
        fields{
          slug
        }
        excerpt
        frontmatter {
          title
        }
      }
  }
```

And I have to rely on either *fileAbsolutePath* or *slug* field containing "/Variants/" text to distinguish parent from a child later in code (to count product variants on home page and to show it in the expanded view).

I saw that other people asked [similar questions](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/26752) before, suggesting to use GraphQL schema customization but it seem too complicated.

I was wondering if there is an easier way to do what I'm doing in Gatsby or maybe there is a ready-made solution for paren/child structure?

I'm using Gatsby 2.3.23 together with MarkdownRemark.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that the ideal, cleaner and elegant solution is using a [GraphQL schema customization](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/graphql-data-layer/schema-customization/), however, if it's not an option for you, I'm thinking of a kind of `key` value for each parent product so can be used as filter identifier. Given:

```
src/posts
│
└───Product_A
│   │   index.md
```

So in the index.md:

```
---
key: product A
someField: Some value
someField2: Some value 2
---
```

Then, in your query fields you can do something like:

```
  allMarkdownRemark( filter: {key: {eq: "product A" }){
    edges {
      node {
        fileAbsolutePath
        fields{
          slug
        }
        excerpt
        frontmatter {
          title
        }
      }
  }
```

And so on for the rest.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I did.
I had to keep two-level folder structure.
So in gatsby-node.js onCreateNode() I've added parent key (based on the folder structure that I read from fileAbsolutePath). And later I use that key in page templates.